# adding value to dictionary using update()

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to add a value into my dictionary.

my dictionary:

```
a = {'a':[a,b,c],'b':[e,f,g]}
```

When I use the command `a.update({'c':[j,k,l]})` and I try to print, I get a value of None

I am trying to get

```
a = {'a':[a,b,c],'b':[e,f,g], 'c':[j,k,l]}
```

Comment: No problem here: `>>> a = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}
>>> a.update({'c': [9]})
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [9], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`update`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) updates the dict *in place* and returns `None`.

Print `a` instead of the value returned by `udpate`.

Docs:

```
D.update([E, ]**F) -> **None**.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
If E present and has a .keys() method, does:     for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
If E present and lacks .keys() method, does:     for (k, v) in E: D[k] = v
In either case, this is followed by: for k in F: D[k] = F[k]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works:

```
>>> a = {'a':['a','b','c'],'b':['e','f','g']}
>>> a.update({'c':['j','k','l']})
>>> print a
{'a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c': ['j', 'k', 'l'], 'b': ['e', 'f', 'g']}
>>>
```

The problem is that [`dict.update`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) is an in-place method.  Meaning, it always returns `None`.

As I showed in my example, what you need to do is put the call to `dict.update` on its own line and then print the dictionary after that line.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {'a':['a','b','c'],'b':['e','f','g']}

a.update({'c':['j','k','l']})

print a
```

gives:

```
{'a': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c': ['j', 'k', 'l'], 'b': ['e', 'f', 'g']}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `update()`  method is inplace and returns `None`. The dict is modified by itself:

```
>>> a = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}
>>> a
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
>>> a.update({'c': [9]})
>>> a
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [9], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

I guess you're rewriting it with something like: `a = a.update({'c': [9]})` and because of the `None` result, you get `None`...